# OpenCL and OpenCV conflict

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

In our project we decided to migrate OpenCL to enhance image processing. After the migration the project didn't work. So, we tried a minimal code from OpenCL and determinded that if OpenCV is in use the project dosn't work.

For Example

```
int main(){
  cv::Mat mat;

  std::vector<cl::Platform> all_platforms;
  cl::Platform::get(&all_platforms);

  std::cout <<"fertig.";
  return 0;
}
```

crashes at cl::Platform::get().

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cl::Error'
what():  clGetPlatformIDs
```

I compiled it with

```
gcc test.cpp -lOpenCl -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui
```

If I let out this little commandline "cv::Mat mat" everything is fine. So, what's the problem?

I am using Intel OpenCl Driver: 1.2-4.4.0.117.

Comment: What does `-opencv_core -opencv_highgui` mean?  Are you missing some 'l's in there?

Comment: yah, you're right. Edited.

Comment: Does anything change if you try OpenCV with OpenCL disabled? Since you are using opencv 3.0, opencl is enabled by default. Maybe there are some strange interferences?